Custom shiny UI with multiple tabs and bucket list
I have made a shiny UI where I want people to be able to able to add an additional bin on a tab and then be able to drag an element from the first bucket on the tab into the second bucket.
I am able to populate the first bucket and then have the second bucket be added using 'Add Bin' button however I cannot drag an element from the first bucket into the second (or subsequent buckets).
Any assistance I would be grateful for.
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets) # For rank_list

# Example data to simulate list_numeric and numeric_variables_revalue
list_numeric <- list(
  "Variable1" = c("Value1", "Value2", "Value3"),
  "Variable2" = c("Value4", "Value5", "Value6")
)
numeric_variables_revalue <- names(list_numeric)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("Text."),
  
  # Create a placeholder for the tabs
  uiOutput("dynamicTabs"),
  
  # Save and Close button
  actionButton("saveClose", "Save and Close")
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Reactive value to store the current state of bins for each tab
  bins <- reactiveVal(lapply(seq_along(numeric_variables_revalue), function(i) {
    list(
      labels = list_numeric[[i]],  # Initial labels
      count = 1
    )
  }))
  
  # Render UI for dynamic tabs
  output$dynamicTabs <- renderUI({
    do.call(tabsetPanel, lapply(seq_along(numeric_variables_revalue), function(i) {
      tabPanel(
        numeric_variables_revalue[i],
        h2(numeric_variables_revalue[i]),
        uiOutput(paste0("rank_list_ui_", i)),
        actionButton(paste0("add_bin_", i), "Add Bin")
      )
    }))
  })
  
  # Render rank lists for each tab
  observe({
    lapply(seq_along(numeric_variables_revalue), function(i) {
      output[[paste0("rank_list_ui_", i)]] <- renderUI({
        lapply(seq_len(bins()[[i]]$count), function(j) {
          rank_list(
            text = paste("Bin", j),
            labels = if (j == 1) bins()[[i]]$labels else NULL,  # Fill first bin, others empty
            input_id = paste0("rank_list_", i, "_", j)
          )
        })
      })
    })
  })
  
  # Observe Add Bin button click for each tab
  observeEvent(input$add_bin_1, {
    current_bins <- bins()
    current_bins[[1]]$count <- current_bins[[1]]$count + 1
    bins(current_bins)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add_bin_2, {
    current_bins <- bins()
    current_bins[[2]]$count <- current_bins[[2]]$count + 1
    bins(current_bins)
  })
  
  # Observe Save and Close button click
  observeEvent(input$saveClose, {
    # Close the app
    stopApp()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

For @yben
When I try to use sortable I get an error:
Error in : is_add_rank_list(x = dot) is not TRUE
library(shiny)
library(sortable) # For sortable functionality

# Example data to simulate list_numeric and numeric_variables_revalue
list_numeric <- list(
  "Variable1" = c("Value1", "Value2", "Value3"),
  "Variable2" = c("Value4", "Value5", "Value6")
)
numeric_variables_revalue <- names(list_numeric)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("Text."),
  
  # Create a placeholder for the tabs
  uiOutput("dynamicTabs"),
  
  # Save and Close button
  actionButton("saveClose", "Save and Close")
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Reactive value to store the current state of bins for each tab
  bins <- reactiveVal(lapply(seq_along(numeric_variables_revalue), function(i) {
    list(
      labels = list_numeric[[i]],  # Initial labels
      count = 1
    )
  }))
  
  # Render UI for dynamic tabs
  output$dynamicTabs <- renderUI({
    do.call(tabsetPanel, lapply(seq_along(numeric_variables_revalue), function(i) {
      tabPanel(
        numeric_variables_revalue[i],
        h2(numeric_variables_revalue[i]),
        uiOutput(paste0("sortable_ui_", i)),
        actionButton(paste0("add_bin_", i), "Add Bin")
      )
    }))
  })
  
  # Render sortable lists for each tab
  observe({
    lapply(seq_along(numeric_variables_revalue), function(i) {
      output[[paste0("sortable_ui_", i)]] <- renderUI({
        bucket_list(
          header = NULL,
          group_name = paste0("sortable_group_", i),
          orientation = "horizontal",
          lapply(seq_len(bins()[[i]]$count), function(j) {
            add_rank_list(
              text = paste("Bin", j),
              labels = if (j == 1) bins()[[i]]$labels else NULL,
              input_id = paste0("sortable_list_", i, "_", j)
            )
          })
        )
      })
    })
  })
  
  # Observe Add Bin button click for each tab
  observeEvent(input$add_bin_1, {
    current_bins <- bins()
    current_bins[[1]]$count <- current_bins[[1]]$count + 1
    bins(current_bins)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add_bin_2, {
    current_bins <- bins()
    current_bins[[2]]$count <- current_bins[[2]]$count + 1
    bins(current_bins)
  })
  
  # Observe Save and Close button click
  observeEvent(input$saveClose, {
    # Close the app
    stopApp()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Try to use the sortable package it provides inputs with drag-and-drop and you could render more options dynamically.

@yben do you know what I did wrong in my added sortable code version that I added?
